# When (and why) did the reputation graph change to a 60 day limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation-page

The reputation graph in everyone's profiles used to be able to select a wider range than this. Now it says "Maximum 60 days allowed". This is rather a disappointing change. Any particular reason?

Comment: If you really need stats back more than 60 days, grab the SO download and install it locally and do all your reporting as you wish! :-)

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't tell you when exactly, but I know it's been a couple months at least.

Comment: Are you sure? I'm pretty sure I used this a week or two ago.

Comment: Joel, the limit is at most 2 weeks old...